# I installed symfony 3, ran the server and got a connection refused when I ran the webserver

Tags: php, apache, web, symfony

I auto-generated a Symfony 3 application with the CLI they provide and I put it inside my `www/html` folder, which my apache2 server serves its files from:

Then I tried to do:

```
$ php bin/console server:start -vvv

$ sudo php bin/console server:start -vvv

$ php bin/console server:start 127.0.0.1:2040
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
[2016-03-18 00:06:14] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/var/www/html/sample_symfony_blog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"level":28928}
```

I can't find any concrete answer on what this could be, other than it could be that the port is busy, which is why I tried with port 2040 as well.

Symfony official's documentation talks about some user rights running the webserver and that the PHP CLI should have the same permissions or something? I'm not that used to configure Apache/Ubuntu so I don't know what to do to test it out in that regard. Any hints?

Comment: if you are running web server from symfony, I think you are actually using php to run the server, not apache. It is much simpler to just point apache vhost to public/index.php than to run your own PHP server. If you want to run that server, it might be an issue of [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) (I assume you are using Ubuntu).

Comment: Yeah after i wrote the question i just realized that when running a webserver i ofc didn't have to put symfony inside of my www/html relying on apache. So i created a new project somewhere in Documents, started the server - same result. Then i would like some debugging so i tried to add: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); To my etc/php5/cli/php.ini  file....  that made it work though, but ONLY because there is a php error, so putting 2 and 2 together, i have something in my php.ini file when being executed blocks the server. hmm...

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of resurrecting a really old question, I'd like to add a note from recent experience. I had a working Symfony 3 installation using PHP 5.6 that stopped working when I upgraded to PHP 7.1. Trying to start the built-in server gave me the same connection refused error, which led me here.

Ultimately, I solved the problem by running `php bin/symfony_requirements`. The output told me that I had xdebug.scream turned on in my php.ini and it had to be turned off. Fixing that made the problem go away.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: you saved me :-D

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i realized putting a error early in my /etc/php5/cli/php.ini file, made it work, obviously because my  php.ini file ran a configuration that made it not work, i did not find out which file option that caused it to happen.  The reason i even tried to fix this problem was because i couldn't get it to work by accessing it via my apache2 webserver on localhost:80/my_project,  but instead had to access  localhost:80/my_project/web which works just fine, so im doing that instead of running my own builtin php server - because thats the way i have to run it in production anyway so. Thanks to anyone who sat down and tried to figure it out :)

Comment: i'm sorry i have the same problem i can't seem to find what is wrong and didn't find your answer that clear

Comment: Hi. So, now its a pretty long time ago, but my problem was that i didn't know the difference between running it with my own php server via the symfony CLI tool, and running it via the apache server. Obviously you only need one of these solutions, as i can see via my answer what it appears that i did was to put the symfony project into www/html folder, had apache2 service running and was able to access it through localhost:80/my_project/web ...   the alternative is to run the php server that symfony gives you, and then you should take it out of the www/html folder, e.g. in documents.